# How do I get a specific icon that depends on another element from the HTML in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, angular, cypress

This is the code [image: code here]

Screenshot of page[image: Screenshot of page]

How do I get a specific icon that depends on another element from the HTML in Cypress?
I need to get the 'delete_forever' element.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what exactly you want ?

Comment: Can you please share your table code so I will understand brifly?

Comment: Something like `cy.contains('mat-cell', 'Cypress2021-02-28').siblings('mat-cell:contains("delete_forever")')`.

Comment: Or maybe `cy.contains('mat-cell', 'Cypress2021-02-28').parent().find('mat-icon:contains("delete_forever")')`. You need to learn the commands and try out variations on your page.

Comment: Hiram K. Hackenbacker its realy works! Thank you so much!